# How to stop select from opening when closing chip in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

For this example from vuetify.com

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqoxXY?&editors=101

autocomplete with chips, when I cancel a chip, how do I get it to not make the select menu open?

i tried `@click.stop="..."` but it doesn't work

on the chip event

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you remove `box` prop from your `v-autocomplete`, it won't open the menu when you remove a chips by clicking on the cross.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzJJjr?&editors=101)

Comment: Side note, in case this helps anyone: like the `box` prop, I have found that the `solo` prop causes the same problem with the menu opening.