# How to prevent v-autocomplete from opening the dropdown drawer when clicking on a chip

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm building an app with VueJS + Vuetify and using "v-autocomplete" as a multi-selection dropdown. However, I can't find a way to prevent the dropdown drawer from opening when I click to remove an item.

**Codepen example:** https://codepen.io/rafacarneiro/pen/abOVEzw?editable=true&editors=101

Code used when removing an item:

```js
<v-chip
   v-bind="data.attrs"
   :input-value="data.selected"
   close
   @click="data.select"
   @click:close="remove(data.item)"
>
```

**Current behaviour:** when clicking on the "X" icon on a selected item, the item is removed, however, the dropdown drawer opens at the same time. I would like to prevent this behaviour when removing an item, but I've been struggling to find a way to do it.

Comment: I tried with the `stop` without success

Answer (score 3):

Looks almost like a dup of: [How to stop select from opening when closing chip in vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268291/how-to-stop-select-from-opening-when-closing-chip-in-vuetify)

If you remove the `filled` prop from the v-autocomplete it will work.

Comment: The problem is, if we add some other styling props (like "solo" and/or "outlined"), it will not work even without the filled prop. I've updated the Codepen now.

Answer (score 2):

`@click.stop` should make the job